# asp.net Dynamic Controls

Tags: asp.net

i am creating dynamic controls in my asp.net application. Each time i have to recreate the control to display, in this case values in that control are getting deleted.

Comment: Why don't you accept answers to your questions? You've asked 17 questions and accepted 0 answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take care on Your own about restoring controls and their state.

Here You will find more:
https://web.archive.org/web/20211031102347/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx

Comment: Thanku... I got the solution by using Page_Init event