# Textbox values disappear on postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have an asp.net page with a button that adds an additional row to a gridview for input to the database. The gridview consists of 3 textboxes(template fields), when I add a row the information already entered somehow disappears on the postback. I want the button to add additional rows without disspelling the data in the other rows, until I hit the submit button. Here's my code

```
Private Sub AddNewRowToGrid()
    Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0
    If ViewState("CurrentTable") IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim dtCurrentTable As DataTable = DirectCast(ViewState("CurrentTable"), DataTable)
        Dim drCurrentRow As DataRow = Nothing
        If dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For i As Integer = 1 To dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count
                'extract the TextBox values
                Dim box1 As TextBox = DirectCast(gvOLIAdj.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(1).FindControl("txtAdjAppr"), TextBox)
                Dim box2 As TextBox = DirectCast(gvOLIAdj.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(2).FindControl("txtAdjAmt"), TextBox)
                Dim box3 As TextBox = DirectCast(gvOLIAdj.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(3).FindControl("txtCmmts"), TextBox)
                drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow()
                drCurrentRow("Approval Date") = box1.ToString
                dtCurrentTable.Rows(i - 1)("Total Amount") = box2.ToString
                dtCurrentTable.Rows(i - 1)("Comments") = box3.ToString
                'dtCurrentTable.Rows(i - 1)("Initials") = 
                rowIndex += 1
            Next
            dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow)
            ViewState("CurrentTable") = dtCurrentTable
            gvOLIAdj.DataSource = dtCurrentTable
            gvOLIAdj.DataBind()
        End If
    Else
        Response.Write("ViewState is null")
    End If
    'Set Previous Data on Postbacks
    'SetPreviousData()
End Sub

Private Sub SetPreviousData()
    Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0
    If ViewState("CurrentTable") IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim dats As DataTable = DirectCast(ViewState("CurrentTable"), DataTable)
        If dats.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To dats.Rows.Count - 1
                Dim box1 As TextBox = DirectCast(gvOLIAdj.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(1).FindControl("txtAdjAppr"), TextBox)
                Dim box2 As TextBox = DirectCast(gvOLIAdj.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(2).FindControl("txtAdjAmt"), TextBox)
                Dim box3 As TextBox = DirectCast(gvOLIAdj.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(3).FindControl("txtCmmts"), TextBox)
                box1.Text = dats.Rows(i)("Approval Date").ToString()
                box2.Text = dats.Rows(i)("Total Amount").ToString()
                box3.Text = dats.Rows(i)("Comments").ToString()
                rowIndex += 1
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a Page_Load function? Posting that will help you get an answer, I suspect.

Comment: yea the page load is there but it has nothing to do with this, they aren't connected in any way

Comment: PageLoad can come into play on postback.

Comment: Can you elaborate? do you have a solution? when I debug it doesn't even hit page load so I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: when you refresh your page the Page_Load event fires, everytime.

Comment: Then is there a way to skip that for this situation or is there a fix??

Comment: you can do if not IsPostback then ...your code endif, but I doubt that will solve your problem. I think your problem is probably like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453489/asp-net-dynamic-controls

Comment: you may also want to read joel's answer on this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786074/dynamic-user-controls-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two reasons why this may be happening:

1. When you create controls dynamically it is VERY difficult to
   retrieve the values in the code behind after postback
2. Your controls have the read-only attribute set in the raw HTML

You may want to try old-fashioned methods such as Request.Form http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx